# Golang issue with DNS response > 512 bytes on Mac OS X (cannot unmarshal DNS message)

Tags: macos, go, dns

One of our users gets the following error when trying to do DNS resolution.

```
Post https://api.heroku.com/login: dial tcp: lookup api.heroku.com on 8.8.4.4:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message
```

The user was helpful enough to supply me with `dig` output and it appears that the DNS response is indeed larger than 512 bytes.  Is there anything that I can do to fix this issue with go and large DNS responses?  We are currently using `go version go1.6.1 darwin/amd64`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.4.4 api.heroku.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55215
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 12

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.heroku.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.heroku.com. 21 IN CNAME midgard.heroku.com.
midgard.heroku.com. 441 IN CNAME midgard.herokussl.com.
midgard.herokussl.com. 3137 IN CNAME elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 51 IN A 54.243.105.250
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 51 IN A 54.225.188.133
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 51 IN A 23.21.149.112

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com. 140079 IN NS g.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS j.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS i.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS b.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS k.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS a.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS e.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS c.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS l.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS m.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS f.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS h.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS d.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
g.gtld-servers.net. 124660 IN A 192.42.93.30
j.gtld-servers.net. 91373 IN A 192.48.79.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 119024 IN A 192.43.172.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 119025 IN A 192.33.14.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 27063 IN A 192.52.178.30
a.gtld-servers.net. 16745 IN A 192.5.6.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 123106 IN A 192.12.94.30
c.gtld-servers.net. 153632 IN A 192.26.92.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 22933 IN A 192.41.162.30
f.gtld-servers.net. 107336 IN A 192.35.51.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 29637 IN A 192.54.112.30
d.gtld-servers.net. 119025 IN A 192.31.80.30

;; Query time: 48 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 14 07:37:57 2016
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 609
```

Comment: I'm not able to get that large a response from any resolver to test this. Can you test if there's a difference with `GODEBUG=netdns=cgo` vs `GODEBUG=netdns=go`?

Comment: Note that `dig` does not use the OS's DNS resolver, so the difference you're seeing in its behavior might not have anything to do with what's happening with the `go` program. To test OS X's resolver, try `dscacheutil -q host -a name api.heroku.com` (but it won't give as detailed output).

Comment: @JimB I asked the user to try `GODEBUG=netdns=cgo` which had no effect, will ask the user to try `GODEBUG=netdns=go` though I assumed that was the default

Comment: Please supply sample `go` code - the `dig` output is useless because dig 9.8.3 as bundled with OSX doesn't use `edns` by default to permit UDP messages above 512 octets.   I note that I also can't get that long an answer from Google DNS at this moment.

Comment: NB: this _may_ have been a Google DNS bug at the time - a normal query to google shouldn't result in all of those records in the authority and additional sections.

Comment: This is go bug.
I made detailed bug report here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21160